# GAS Spreadsheet copyTo() Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am looking to implement a kind of "archive function" which takes a Google spreadsheet sheet and copy's it to an archive spreadsheet.

The script currently uses `Sheet.copyTo(Spreadsheet)`, which works absolutely fine for static sheets, but when cells contain formulas, when it copy's to the new spreadsheet, these formula references obviously break.

With `Range.copyTo()` there is the option to add advanced arguments for `{contentOnly: true}`, but I can't see a similar thing for `Sheet.copyTo()`

Does anybody know a workaround for this, or is the only way I am able to achieve this is to `getValues()`, `getFormulas()`... And replicate the sheet in the new sheet?

Comment: In my knowledge, there is no contentOnly option in `sheet.copyTo` method. You will have to use `Range.copyTo()` over the entire sheet and have contentOnly true or use `getDisplayValues()`

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the longer workaround for the time being

Answer (score -1):

Creating an array with data having .getDisplayValues() attributes and throw that to the new sheet. Simple :)